# Clarifying “error-prone” nuance of spread syntax vs. assignment in Javascript

Tags: spread-syntax

I know that the assignment of one variable to another is done by shared reference so that when you set var c = b; and then you do some change change to c such as c.cool = 'new'; then b gets affected as well. `console.log(b.cool); // new`

However, coming to Javascript from different programming languages, I remember there is an error prone ‘gotcha’ when using the spread syntax var c = {…b}.
Can somebody clarify this ‘gotcha’ and any nuances to keep track of?

Answer (score -2):

TLDR;
When `var b = { …an object of your choice …};` the subsequent assignment of `var c = b;` is an assignment by shared reference.  You can think of both `b` and `c` as pointing to the same thing in memory; things that change `c` will change `b` and vice-versa, change `b` and it will change `c`.

Assignment by spread syntax `var c = {...b}` means something slightly more complicated.  Specifically, the behavior is different is for top-level properties and for nested properties.  For top-level properties, there is a deep copy (leaving `c` and `b` are independent) but for nested-properties, there is a shallow copy (changes to `c` and `b` affect the other.)  (SO DEEP COPY FOR TOP-LEVEL PROPERTIES, SHALLOW COPY FOR NESTED-PROPERTIES).

So what are SHALLOW COPY vs. DEEP COPY?

*From free code camp:*

> A shallow copy creates a new object or array, but it only copies the
> references to the properties of the original object or array. In other
> words, the new object or array has the same values for its properties
> as the original, but the properties themselves still reference the
> same values in memory. This means that any changes made to the
> properties of the new object or array will also affect the original
> object or array, and vice versa.
>
> A deep copy, on the other hand, creates a new object or array. It also
> copies the values of the properties of the original object or array,
> rather than just the references. This means that any changes made to
> the new object or array will not affect the original object or array,
> and vice versa.

So let’s look at an example and change both a top-level property and then a nested property.  And remember, you can change `c` and see how to affects `b`, but you can also change `b` and see how it changes `c`.

**REGULAR ASSIGNMENT**

```
// VIA REGULAR ASSIGNMENT 
let b = { top1: 'zero', top2: 'zero', nested1: { inside1: 'zero' }, nested2: { inside2: 'zero'}};
let c = b; // Regular assignment

// Starting from C -> B
// change a top-level property
c.top1 = 'one';

// change the nested property
c.nested1.inside1 = 'one';

// let's look at the console for c and it's corresponding property for b
console.log(c.top1); // one
console.log(b.top1); // one

console.log(c.nested1.inside1); // one
console.log(b.nested1.inside1); // one

// You can also go the other way: B->C
// change a top-level property
b.top2 = 'two';

// change the nested property
b.nested2.inside2 = 'two';

// let's look at the console for b and it's corresponding property for c    
console.log(b.top2); //two
console.log(c.top2); //two

console.log(b.nested2.inside2); //two
console.log(c.nested2.inside2); //two
```

So far ^ that’s pretty consistent, anything you change in `c` gets reflected in `b`.

However, the following is the “gotcha” of spread syntax that ... well ... does not feel as clean from a programming language perspective, and that can be a bit user error prone.

When assigning a variable via spread syntax, a deep copy is made at the top-level properties, meaning you get NEW copies of top-level properties but only a shallow copy (SHARED REFERENCES) for any nested properties.  Here is are example that shows the difference in how top-level vs nested properties are treated.

**SPREAD SYNTAX**

```
// VIA SPREAD SYNTAX 
let b = { top1: 'zero', top2: 'zero', nested1: { inside1: 'zero' }, nested2: { inside2: 'zero'}};
let c = { ...b }; // spread syntax — this is a deep copy at the top level, and shallow copy for nested properties

// Starting from C -> B
// change a top-level property
c.top1 = 'one';

// change the nested property
c.nested1.inside1 = 'one';

// let's look at the console for c and it's corresponding property for b
console.log(c.top1); // one
console.log(b.top1); // zero - NOTE: B’s top-level properties are unaffected

console.log(c.nested1.inside1); // one
console.log(b.nested1.inside1); // one - NOTE: B’s nested properties change

// You can also go the other way: B->C
// change a top-level property
b.top2 = 'two';

// change the nested property
b.nested2.inside2 = 'two';

// let's look at the console for b and it's corresponding property for c    
console.log(b.top2); //two
console.log(c.top2); //zero - NOTE: C’s top-level properties are unaffected

console.log(b.nested2.inside2); //two
console.log(c.nested2.inside2); //two - NOTE: C’s nested properties change
```

**ADDING A COMPLETELY NEW NESTED PROPERTY**

What happens you later ADD a completely new nested property to one or the other?

**REGULAR ASSIGNMENT(ADDING A COMPLETELY NEW NESTED PROPERTY)**

```
// VIA REGULAR ASSIGNMENT(ADDING A COMPLETELY NEW NESTED PROPERTY)
let b = { top1: 'zero', top2: 'zero', nested1: { inside1: 'zero' }, nested2: { inside2: 'zero'}};
let c = b; // Regular assignment

// Starting from C -> B
// change a top-level property
c.newNested = 'yup';
c.newNested.newInside = 'cannot do this';
c.newNested = { newInside2: 'yup - this works'};

console.log(c.newNested); // {"newInside2": "yup - this works"}
console.log(c.newNested.newInside) // undefined
console.log(c.newNested.newInside2) // yup - this works

console.log(b.newNested); // {"newInside2": "yup - this works"}
console.log(b.newNested.newInside); // undefined
console.log(b.newNested.newInside2); // yup - this works - NOTE! The new nested property on C does affect B. 

// Let’s do this the reverse way B -> C
// change a top-level property
c.newNested2 = 'yup';
c.newNested2.newInside = 'cannot do this';
c.newNested2 = { newInside2: 'yup - this works'};

console.log(b.newNested2); // {"newInside2": "yup - this works"}
console.log(b.newNested2.newInside); // undefined
console.log(b.newNested2.newInside2); // yup - this works 

console.log(c.newNested2); // {"newInside2": "yup - this works"}
console.log(c.newNested2.newInside) // undefined
console.log(c.newNested2.newInside2) // yup - this works - NOTE! The new nested property on B does affect C.
```

**SPREAD SYNTAX (ADDING A COMPLETELY NEW NESTED PROPERTY)**

```
// VIA SPREAD SYNTAX (ADDING A COMPLETELY NEW NESTED PROPERTY)
let b = { top1: 'zero', top2: 'zero', nested1: { inside1: 'zero' }, nested2: { inside2: 'zero'}};
let c = {...b}; // Regular assignment

// Starting from C -> B
// change a top-level property
c.newNested = 'yup';
c.newNested.newInside = 'cannot do this';
c.newNested = { newInside2: 'yup - this works'};

console.log(c.newNested); // {"newInside2": "yup - this works"}
console.log(c.newNested.newInside) // undefined
console.log(c.newNested.newInside2) // yup - this works

console.log(b.newNested); // undefined - the error here makes it such that the new two errors will definitely occur
console.log(b.newNested.newInside); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties or undefined (reading ‘newInside’)
console.log(b.newNested.newInside2); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties or undefined (reading ‘newInside2’)

// Let’s do this the reverse way B -> C
// change a top-level property
b.newNested2 = 'yup';
b.newNested2.newInside = 'cannot do this';
b.newNested2 = { newInside2: 'yup - this works'};

console.log(b.newNested2); // {newInside2: ‘yup - this works’}
console.log(b.newNested2.newInside) // undefined
console.log(b.newNested2.newInside2) // yup - this works

console.log(c.newNested2); // undefined - the error here makes it such that the new two errors will definitely occur
console.log(c.newNested2.newInside); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties or undefined (reading ‘newInside’)
console.log(c.newNested2.newInside2); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties or undefined (reading ‘newInside2’)
```

**COMPLICATING THINGS EVEN MORE - PASS-BY-VALUE (PRIMITIVE TYPES)**

Just to make things slightly more confusing.
The above paradigm really only works when `b` is an object.
If `b` is a primitive value (number, string, boolean, null, undefined, symbol), then it’s called ‘assign-by-value’ and the behavior of var c = b; means something different.  `c` gets its own set of values.   The examples below show the difference:

```
// BASE CASE
let b = 'zero';
let c = b;

console.log(c) // zero
console.log(b) // zero

// REASSIGN C AND SEE IF IT AFFECTS B
let b = 'zero'; 
let c = b; 
c = 'one'; 

console.log(c); // one
console.log(b); // zero - NOTE: b is not affected
```

Referenced:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-comparison-operators-how-to-compare-objects-for-equality-in-js/

https://javascript.info/object-copy

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-assigning-values-vs-assigning-references/

[https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600#:~:text=On%20variable%20assignment%2C%20the%20scalar,at%20other%20variables%20or%20references](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600#:%7E:text=On%20variable%20assignment%2C%20the%20scalar,at%20other%20variables%20or%20references)